# How to swap in raydium as fast as possible?

Tags: web3.js, solana-sdk, swap

Question is on the title; How to swap tokens as fast as possible. I am using raydium sdk but in that, i need lp infos and market info. Can I make a swap without getting them? Or if i need them, what is the fastest way to get them? GPA call is slow.